# non-type object problem in useing Beautiful soup to scrape data from LinkedIn profile

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a Linkedin profile and here is a screenshot for HTML tags for profile web page as follows:

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to call the `<li>` tag using the class name as per the below screenshot but returning a message that this class is non-type or has no text.

The problem is that not only this tag coming as non type but all tags in the webpage returning as empty even though there is a text within it.

[image: Code]

Comment: Your example `soup.find()` should work fine but the error appears to be for different code. In effect `soup.find()` is not matching any item so returns `None`. You then don't test this and pass the result to `.text` (i.e. you do both calls in one go)

Comment: You should consider using [`soup.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) when trying to match multiple classes.